# AngularJS setting formData with an object

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using a formData object to pass some data to a PHP backend. One of the values I wish to pass is an object. I am seting the data values as follows:

```
var dataObj = new FormData();

myIds = [];
myIds = ["478", "581", "122"];

dataObj.append(test.ids, my.ids);
```

If dump the content of the request data I see the following:

```
test => [
     'ids' => '1,2,3'
]
```

As can be seen 'ids' is a string and not an object or array. Why or how it being chnaged to a string and how can I achieve my original aim?

Comment: What is the expected data structure you are aiming for? Also, please provide working code. You can inspect your `dataObj` before sending it to the server with `console.log(...dataObj)`

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` in javascript and `json_decode()` in php

Answer (score 0):

Stringify the array/object and then decode the value in php

JS

```
dataObj.append('ids', JSON.stringify(my.ids));
```

php

```
$ids = json_decode($_POST['ids']);
// or force to array
$ids = json_decode($_POST['ids'], true);
```

Comment: json stringfy will not work in my case as I am not able to modify the php to decode the string on the backend. I have a similar data object which works as I need. When I console.log its' value I get: File {name: "13.jpg", lastModified: 1487617733861, lastModifiedDate: Mon Feb 20 2017 19:08:53 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 83194, …} - I just need the same format for my own object

Comment: oh.... you need to add files themselves to FormData (individually). They can't be sent as json. Your example in question was a lot more basic than that. Also need to prevent the processing if sending with `$http`

Comment: ok...so if can't change php...what format is it expecting the array data in?

Comment: And you can't do anything in the php? For example even the string in the question can be converted to array with `explode()`

Comment: I hvae no control of the php backend

Comment: Then need a more specific structure expected

Comment: field_id => ['_ids' => [1,2,3,456]]